# Accessing component id onPress in react-native

Tags: react-native

This question has been asked before but it seems like all answers I find deal with class-based components.

I have a component with an onPress handler function as follows:

```
<Text id="someId" onPress={(e) => console.log(e)}>
    Some Text
</Text>
```

I need to get 'someId' logged out consistently. Currently, I can only get it via:

```
console.log(e.target._internalFiberInstanceHandleDEV.memoizedProps.id)
```

This doesn't feel right. Is this the official way of getting the id, or are there different ways? The ones I can find use 'this' which seems to be undefined in functional components.

Comment: what you actually want? Your question not clear.